# Make a cell with text and a date into just a date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a cell (`E2`) that says "Manage Hours For 07-25-2013" I want to make a cell that adds a day to whatever day is in `E2`. How do I make that cell have only the date in the answer and not have "manage hours for" in it?

Answer (score 0):

`=DATE(RIGHT(E2,4),MID(E2,18,2),MID(E2,21,2))+1`

Here this should work, adjust the `mid(` functions to properly relate to the characters in the cell, this *should* work with what you have

Answer (score 0):

```
=RIGHT(E2,10)+1
```

This will return the Excel number value of the date. The cell can then be formatted as a date.

Or if you want to avoid having to change the cell's format, you can wrap the whole thing in a `TEXT` function:

```
=TEXT(RIGHT(E2,10)+1,"mm-dd-yyyy")
```